# How can I choose which GPU to use from grub using vgaswitcheroo?

Tags: grub2, intel-graphics, ati, gpu, vgaswitcheroo

I have a notebook with switchable AMD/Intel Graphics. I use, successfully, vgaswitcheroo to choose the active GPU and disable the unused one by a script in rc.local.

However, I would like to be able to choose the active GPU at startup, ideally by a different grub entry for each GPU. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,